# Generating OAuth 1 Signature in PHP

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to connect to the [LivePerson Engagement History API](https://developers.liveperson.com/engagement-history-api-methods.html) and I'm running into an issue that I believe is related to the signature being generated.

First off, the API already provides the necessary consumer key, consumer secret, access token, and token secret. So I don't have to go through the process of retrieving those. In order to access their API I just have to [provide the auth header](https://developers.liveperson.com/guides-gettingstarted.html). I've mocked everything up using Postman and it all works correctly. The issue is when I try to generate my own timestamp/nonce/signature in my class.

Here's the method from my class that sends the cURL request:

```
private function execute($options = array())
{
    if (!isset($options['url'])) {
        return;
    }

    $ch = curl_init($options['url']);

    $method = (isset($options['method'])) ? $options['method'] : 'GET';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

    if (isset($options['auth']) && $options['auth']) {
        $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $nonce = $this->getNonce(11);
        $version = "1.0";
        $signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        $signature = $this->generateSignature($options, $timestamp, $nonce, $signatureMethod, $version);

        $authHeader = "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{$this->consumerKey}\",oauth_token=\"{$this->accessToken}\",oauth_signature_method=\"{$signatureMethod}\",oauth_timestamp=\"{$timestamp}\",oauth_nonce=\"{$nonce}\",oauth_version=\"{$version}\",oauth_signature=\"{$signature}\"";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            $authHeader,
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ));
    }

    if (isset($options['body']) && !empty($options['body'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($options['body']));
    }

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

The `getNonce` method I copied pretty much directly from https://github.com/BaglerIT/OAuthSimple/blob/master/src/OAuthSimple.php.

Here's the method I've written to generate the signature (which has been cobbled together from various SO posts and other sources):

```
protected function generateSignature($request, $timestamp, $nonce, $signatureMethod, $version)
{
    $base = $request['method'] . "&" . rawurlencode($request['url']) . "&"
        . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
        . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce)
        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($signatureMethod)
        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $timestamp
        . "&oauth_version=" . $version);

    $key = rawurlencode($this->consumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->tokenSecret);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));

    return $signature;
}
```

I can actually copy and paste the authorization header from Postman into my `$authHeader` variable, and replace everything except the timestamp/nonce/signature, and it works.

The response I'm getting from their server right now is `[code] => 0005` but I can't find anything in their docs about response codes.

Edit: I had missed looking at the response header - the exact error is invalid signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 things I changed to get this to work.

1. I was missing the `oauth_token` when creating the base string for the signature
2. According to the [OAuth Core 1.0 documentation](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process), "Parameters are sorted by name, using lexicographical byte value ordering."

So I ended up re-ordering the parameters to be alphabetical. Here's what the code for generating the base string ended up looking like:

```
$base = $request['method'] . "&" . rawurlencode($request['url']) . "&"
        . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
        . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce)
        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($signatureMethod)
        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($timestamp)
        . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($this->accessToken)
        . "&oauth_version=" . rawurlencode($version));
```

I also re-ordered the params in the auth header to match the order of the base string:

```
$authHeader = "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{$this->consumerKey}\",oauth_nonce=\"{$nonce}\",oauth_signature_method=\"{$signatureMethod}\",oauth_timestamp=\"{$timestamp}\",oauth_token=\"{$this->accessToken}\",oauth_version=\"{$version}\",oauth_signature=\"{$signature}\"";
```

Comment: hey I'm also facing the same problem by seeing your code ```Oauth_signature``` is working fine. But I'm getting response as ```bad request 400```. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$base = $request['method']
        . '&' . rawurlencode($request['url'])
        . '&' . rawurlencode('oauth_consumer_key=' . $this->consumerKey)
        . rawurlencode('&oauth_nonce=' . $nonce)
        . rawurlencode('&oauth_signature_method=' . $signatureMethod)
        . rawurlencode('&oauth_timestamp=' . $timestamp)
        . rawurlencode('&oauth_version=' . $version)
        . rawurlencode('&' . http_build_query($data));

$key = rawurlencode($this->consumerSecret) . '&';

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', $base, $key, true)));
```

If you do a POST, make sure to include your posted data, otherwise the signature will not validate.

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{$consumerKey}\",oauth_signature_method=\"{$signatureMethod}\",oauth_timestamp=\"{$timestamp}\",oauth_nonce=\"{$nonce}\",oauth_version=\"{$version}\",oauth_signature=\"{$oauthSignature}\"",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
```

And the header should be as above

Answer (score 1):

This fixed version worked for me :

```php
function generateOauthSignature($method, $url, $consumerKey, $nonce, $signatureMethod, $timestamp, $version, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret, $tokenValue, $extraParams = array())
    {
        $base = strtoupper($method) . "&" . rawurlencode($url) . "&"
            . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . $consumerKey
            . "&oauth_nonce=" . $nonce
            . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $signatureMethod
            . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $timestamp
            . "&oauth_token=" . $tokenValue
            . "&oauth_version=" . $version);

            if (!empty($extraParams)) {
                $base .= rawurlencode("&" . http_build_query($extraParams));
            }

        $key = rawurlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($tokenSecret);
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));

        return rawurlencode($signature);
    }
```

The following twitter thread helped me : https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-generate-oauth-signature-when-post-json-body-in-php/87581

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the proper setup of the OAuth 1 signature and had a lot of failed attempts. After TGA's hint to have a look how it's done with Twitter, I found out that there is an existing class which may be used out-of-the-box:

**TwitterAPIExchange.php** from the repository https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php.

Even if is called "Twitter...", it may also be used for other OAuth1 APIs. Calls will look like this:

```
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => TOKEN,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => TOKEN_SECRET,
    'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
    'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET
);
$url = "https://api-url.com/api/v4/users/0451432/";
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$postfields = array(
    'groupIds' => '23,24,25',
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
return $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
       ->setPostfields($postfields)
       ->performRequest();
```

It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

This version matches the OAuth PECL library's function so you no longer need it.

```
public static function oauth_get_sbs(
    $requestMethod,
    $requestURL,
    $request_parameters
): string
{
    return $requestMethod . "&" . rawurlencode($requestURL) . "&"
        . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($request_parameters['oauth_consumer_key'])
            . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($request_parameters['oauth_nonce'])
            . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($request_parameters['oauth_signature_method'])
            . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $request_parameters['oauth_timestamp']
            . "&oauth_token=" . $request_parameters['oauth_token']
            . "&oauth_version=" . $request_parameters['oauth_version']);
}
```