# Missing required parameters OAuth API (netsuite)

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, netsuite

enter code hereI just started working with OAuth1 API's calling from `php` using `GuzzleHttp\Client`.
In `postman` it's working fine.In `netsuite` log file I can see only required parameters is missing. I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong.  whenever I'm calling the API I'm getting response as

```
 #message: """
    Client error: `GET https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    {"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"o:errorD (truncated...)
    """
  #code: 400
```

php code

```
$realm = 'xxxxxxx';
$consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$oauth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
$oauth_version = '1.0';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$token_secrect = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$timeStamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
$oauth_none = Str::random(11);

$base = 'GET' . "&" . urlencode('https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/') . "&" . urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . urlencode($consumer_key) . "&oauth_nonce=" . urlencode($oauth_none) . "&oauth_signature_method=" . urlencode($oauth_signature_method) . "&oauth_timestamp=" . urlencode($timeStamp) . "&oauth_token=" . urlencode($oauth_token) . "&oauth_version=" . urlencode($oauth_version) . "&realm=" . urlencode($realm));

$key = urlencode($consumer_secret) . "&" . urlencode($token_secrect);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $base, $key, true));



$authorization = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key=' . $consumer_key . ',oauth_nonce=' . $oauth_none . ',oauth_signature_method=' . $oauth_signature_method . ',oauth_timestamp=' . $timeStamp . ',oauth_token=' . $oauth_token . ',oauth_version=' . $oauth_version . ',realm=' . $realm . ',oauth_signature=' . $oauth_signature . '';


        try {
            $client = new Client();
            $headers = [
                'Authorization' => $authorization,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Cookie' => 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING'
            ];
            $body = '';

            $request = new Request('GET', 'https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/', $headers, $body);
            $res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
            dd('here', $res, $res->getBody());
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            dd($e->getResponse(), $e);
        }
```

[Postman Collection](https://testcadomain.com/issue/demo.postman_collection.json)

Comment: Your `$body = '';` is empty here in your code.

Comment: Postman also gives the PHP code to quickly test with things. This is what I received and should work fine at your end. https://pastebin.com/zpWRYkwk

Comment: In postman also it will work if we remove body. For testing I removed.

Comment: I did the same but timestamp, auth_nonce and auth_signature will be different for every request.

Comment: Can you maintain the order of keys for `Authorization` header? It is `OAuth realm="7085372",oauth_consumer_key="aa54a1f2d8812a4d82e9591bd70644d4ef163aba4c2d0c7181c834621c82bfd6",oauth_token="01d6d61ddcf8caee1ea630e0c4e3685c7330749163eac8f0ebd54580ed12c524",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1666762941",oauth_nonce="6p5vW5ulqst",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="1GTfxTPLUfTS8p1KfDXHgqcAkQVP2Lh%2F6%2FSahrk5T98%3D"` in Postman.

Comment: Also, did this work ? https://pastebin.com/zpWRYkwk

Comment: nope same response. I'm re-ordering the keys in authorization

Comment: if I re-order the authorization keys the response is ```un-authorised 401```

Comment: You are url_encoding twice: `urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . urlencode($consumer_key)......... "&realm=" . urlencode($realm));`. Pretty formatting your code will help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Thanks for pointing out the mistake I will try and let you the status.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP is this correct? ```$base = 'GET' . "&" . urlencode('https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/') . "&" . "oauth_consumer_key=" . urlencode($consumer_key) . "&oauth_nonce=" . urlencode($oauth_none) . "&oauth_signature_method=" . urlencode($oauth_signature_method) . "&oauth_timestamp=" . urlencode($timeStamp) . "&oauth_token=" . urlencode($oauth_token) . "&oauth_version=" . urlencode($oauth_version) . "&realm=" . urlencode($realm);```

Comment: Yes, it looks better. Did you try it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP yeah but same response ```bad request 400```

Comment: Do you still get missing paremeters, or a different message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
$base = 'GET' . "&" . urlencode('https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/') . "&" . urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . urlencode($consumer_key) . "&oauth_nonce=" . urlencode($oauth_none) . "&oauth_signature_method=" . urlencode($oauth_signature_method) . "&oauth_timestamp=" . urlencode($timeStamp) . "&oauth_token=" . urlencode($oauth_token) . "&oauth_version=" . urlencode($oauth_version) . "&realm=" . urlencode($realm));
```

From `urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" .`  to `"&realm=" . urlencode($realm));`, you are url_encoding twice, and you are url_encoding `=` symbols. So your `$authorization` string is absolutely malformed, and it results in missing parameters.

This can occurs when you write such a long line, and it's difficult to see. It's better to write it down this way:

```
$base = 'GET&' . urlencode('https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/')
    . '&oauth_consumer_key=' . urlencode($consumer_key)
    . '&oauth_nonce=' . urlencode($oauth_none)
    . '&oauth_signature_method=' . urlencode($oauth_signature_method)
    . '&oauth_timestamp=' . urlencode($timeStamp)
    . '&oauth_token=' . urlencode($oauth_token)
    . '&oauth_version=' . urlencode($oauth_version)
    . '&realm=' . urlencode($realm);
```

But it's even better to use an array and `http_build_query()` function, this way:

```
$url = 'https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/';

$data = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => $oauth_none,
    'oauth_signature_method' => $oauth_signature_method,
    'oauth_timestamp' => $timeStamp,
    'oauth_token' => $oauth_token,
    'oauth_version' => $oauth_version,
    'realm' => $realm,
);

$base = 'GET&' . urlencode($url) . '&' . http_build_query($data);
```

**Note**.- Also, it's a good idea to use a variable for the url, since you are using it more than 1 time.

However, maybe there are more issues left. I'm not sure if you are are doing well the request.

And it's a good idea to have a function to generate OAuth signature.

**Here you are a remaking of your code**:

```
$url = 'https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$data = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'oauth_nonce' => Str::random(11),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
    'oauth_timestamp' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
    'oauth_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
    'realm' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
);

$oauth_signature = generateOauthSignature(
    'GET',
    $url,
    $data['oauth_consumer_key'],
    $data['oauth_nonce'],
    $data['oauth_signature_method'],
    $data['oauth_timestamp'],
    $data['outh_version'],
    $consumer_secret,
    $token_secret,
    $data['oauth_token'],
    array('realm' => $data['realm']),
);
$authorization = 'OAuth ';
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $authorization .= ',' . $key . '=' . $val;
}
$authorization .= ',oauth_signature=' . $oauth_signature;

try {
    $client = new Client();
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => $authorization,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Cookie' => 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING'
    ];
    $body = '';

    $request = new Request('GET', $url, $headers, $body);
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
    dd('here', $res, $res->getBody());
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    dd($e->getResponse(), $e);
}


function generateOauthSignature($method, $url, $consumerKey, $nonce, $signatureMethod, $timestamp, $version, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret, $tokenValue, $extraParams = array())
{
    $base = strtoupper($method) . "&" . rawurlencode($url) . "&"
        . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . $consumerKey
        . "&oauth_nonce=" . $nonce
        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $signatureMethod
        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $timestamp
        . "&oauth_token=" . $tokenValue
        . "&oauth_version=" . $version);

        if (!empty($extraParams)) {
            $base .= rawurlencode("&" . http_build_query($extraParams));
        }

    $key = rawurlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($tokenSecret);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));

    return rawurlencode($signature);
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing but still getting same response as Missing parameters. ```message: """
    Client error: `GET https://7085372.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    {"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"o:errorD (truncated...)
    """
  #code: 400 ```

Comment: do you think the problem may in headers? while passing authorization keys?

Comment: @matheenulla Did you follow an example from somewhere? If yes, let me know to review it.

Comment: Yes because this is first time I'm using OAuth1 API in php. So I don't have idea how it works before I used to get response as ```un-authorised 401```. After seeing this link ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785040/generating-oauth-1-signature-in-php``` I solved ```un-authorised 401``` error. Now Struggling to fixed this error.

Comment: @matheenulla Uf, that example is so unclear. However, I've edited my answer, see **remaking of your code** and try it.

Comment: You have been very helpful and I appreciate your efforts. I tried this as well, but got the same response from the server. There may be other parameters I'm missing as well. I can only see this many parameters in the ```Postman collection```.  In the netsuite log only it is showing ```MissingRequiredParameter```

Comment: @matheenulla I'm sorry. It will be very useful if we find a clear working example.

Comment: I will try and let you know if I found any solution. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: carlos PHP  after long struggles finally I can able to call the API. I followed this ```https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316911/php-curl-netsuite-api-throws-invalid-login-and-login-audit-throws-invalidsignatu```. Now its working. Thank you once again for your support and help